# Favicon and Title showing locally, but not on website

Tags: html, css, hosting

First, I should mention that I am hosting on a .vip website. My code is simple:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="icon" href="img/Pic.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
```

This works when I host locally through MAMP, but neither the title nor the favicon are showing up on Chrome etc. on any desktop I try.

To add to the mystery (which may be related) none of my extensions are appearing on the URL. For example, if I have a link to a page "dj_page.html", whereas on MAMP it does show [SITE]/dj_page.html, and on my website I would like it to show

```
[SITE].vip/dj_page.html
```

Instead it just remains at

```
[SITE].vip
```

I have cleared the cache on Safari, tried several different computers, but not even the title is showing up properly. Also, does not work if I change the code to, for example,

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://otranscribe.com/favicon.png">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: I was hosting on Heroku and nothing was working. Switched over to Azure and everything worked no problems...

Comment: Why did this work? this shouldn't be the accepted solution. I have the same problem. I am on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: I believe that's what I did? Or are you saying I need to specifically name it favicon.ico?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. The problem may be more deep-rooted, as even the title isn't appearing properly on the tab

Comment: can you refresh the page? ctrl+f5